# Using dlply with pROC

Tags: r, plyr, roc

I'm trying to apply the `roc()` function from the pROC package to specific variables from dataframe `df`, subset on `df$site` which consists of characters that look like "01", "02", "03". The function `roc()` returns a list, so I'm expecting my object `roc_site` to be a list which in turn contains a list of results for each site.

```
roc_site <- dlply(
  .data = df, 
  .variables = "site", 
  .fun = roc, 
  .progress = "text",
  response = df$Risk,
  predictor = df$Rating, 
  na.rm = TRUE, plot = TRUE)
```

This runs successfully, and `roc_site` is a list that consists of one list for each site, but the results for each site are identical; it hasn't split the dataframe apart. What am I missing?

Comment: Sometimes when you cannot figure out what is going on, it helps to replace the "function" inside such a split-apply loop with a simple `print()`. Then you will _see_ what is getting passed.

Comment: That's a great idea; thanks for the tip!

Comment: Or `browser()` so that you can inspect what you're getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function that you pass to `.fun` in `dlply` needs to accept the entire chunk of the data frame as its (first) argument.

So in this case, what you really want is to write your own small function that will take your data frame and calculate what you want. e.g.

```
foo <- function(x){
    roc(x$Risk, x$Rating, na.rm = TRUE, plot = TRUE)
}
```

and then pass that function to `.fun`.

The reason you're getting the identical results is that for each chunk, `dlply` is calling `roc` on your chunk, but passing `df$Risk` and `df$Rating` *each time*, and those are the vectors for the *entire data set*.

Comment: That was amazingly fast and amazingly informative. Thank you very, very much.